# How to call an img from html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

It is possible to put multiple images in js array and when the function is call, one of the image(random) will pop up to the screen?
If not, how can I use .innerHTML to put the image url to `<img src="">`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure:

```js
// Store the image sources in an array:
var imgs = ["http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/abc-gold-logo.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/NBC_logo.svg/779px-NBC_logo.svg.png",
            "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/96/e6/d9/96e6d9e141ac42bf9aad1aaae0a15c61.jpg", 
            "http://fontmeme.com/images/CNN-Logo.jpg",
            "http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/TBS-logo-blue.png",
            "http://www.doddlenews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/fox-tv-logo.jpg"];

// Get reference to the img element
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");

function getRandomImage(){
  // Get random number between 0 and 3 (the length of the array)
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);

  // Set the src and the alt to a random image from the array
  img.src = imgs[rnd];
  img.alt = imgs[rnd];
}

// Get reference to the button
var btn = document.getElementById("getImage");

// When button is clicked, run function
btn.addEventListener("click", getRandomImage);
```

```css
img { width:75px; }
```

```html
<button id="getImage">Click to get random image</button>
<br>
<img src="https://pisces.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/en_US/images/abn/2014/tvv/cat/tv/tv_size4a.jpg;maxHeight=333;maxWidth=333" id="myImage">
```

Also FYI, `.innerHTML` is only for elements that have "content". An `img` element doesn't have a closing tag and therefore, it can't "contain" anything between its opening and closing tags.

Comment: Nice. But can we not have a default image?

Comment: @StevenTran The default image is the first one you see before you click the button (television monitor). It's the one actually written into the HTML `img` tag.

Comment: But can we put it so I will generate a random img?

Comment: @StevenTran That is exactly what the code does. It generates a random number and then uses that number as the index number to pull from the array. This is exactly what your question asked for. Every time you click the button, you call the function that gets a random image path and then updates the display with that new image.

Comment: @StevenTran  Oh, are you asking if we can get rid of the default image and just have a random one come up each time the page is loaded?

Comment: You're kidding me?! A down vote for the correct (and accepted) answer that provides a working example with clear explanations that directly address what was asked. Wow!

Answer (score 0):

Auto random image:

```js
var images = ["https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif",
"https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_edge.gif", 
"https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_firefox.gif", 
"https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_safari.gif", 
"https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_opera.gif"]

function getImage() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img src=" + images[x] + ">";
}

getImage();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to use innerHTML for this. Instead use .setAttribute()

example:

```
 <img id="image1" src="" />

 document.getElementById('image1').setAttribute("href", "xyz.html");
```

Becomes:

```
 <img id="image1" src="xyz.html" />
```

Comment: Do the "href", "xyz.html" just open and run its script?

Comment: This answer doesn't address how to get a random image from an array.

Comment: His question:

IF NOT, how can I use .innerHTML to put the image url to <img src="">?

Answered as asked.